# curl not able to find the redirected url

Tags: php, curl

am trying to fetch the redirected url from this [url](http://www.mediaexpert.pl/td_redirect?tduid=cdddb90f50749342ebe92662d5ae2868&url=http://clickserve.dartsearch.net/link/click?lid=43700006682073804&ds_s_kwgid=58700000455306780&ds_url_v=2&ds_dest_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediaexpert.pl%2Faparaty-kompaktowe%2Faparat-cyfrowy-sony-dsc-hx400vb-czarny,id-220778%3Futm_source%FCAdkEcDcq%26utm_medium%3DXML%26utm_campaign%3D2015-12%0A&utm_medium=linktxt&utm_campaign=2015.11&utm_source=fCAdkEcDcq&utm_content=1831888)...

For this am using the following code...

```
$urlt="http://www.mediaexpert.pl/td_redirect?tduid=cdddb90f50749342ebe92662d5ae2868&url=http://clickserve.dartsearch.net/link/click?lid=43700006682073804&ds_s_kwgid=58700000455306780&ds_url_v=2&ds_dest_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediaexpert.pl%2Faparaty-kompaktowe%2Faparat-cyfrowy-sony-dsc-hx400vb-czarny,id-220778%3Futm_source%fCAdkEcDcq%26utm_medium%3DXML%26utm_campaign%3D2015-12%0A&utm_medium=linktxt&utm_campaign=2015.11&utm_source=fCAdkEcDcq&utm_content=1831888";
//$url = 'http://www.example.com/product/123/';



$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlt);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Must be set to true so that PHP follows any "Location:" header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$ufr = curl_exec($ch); // $a will contain all headers

$urnt = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); // This is what you need, it will return you the last effective URL
echo $urnt;
```

But its not working...although this code is working for other urls...am i missing anything here...please guide me.

Comment: please elaborate on what "its not working" means, exactly.

Comment: @DanielStenberg...its not returning the redirected url...

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the server is not responding with an `HTTP` redirect.

The response body seems to contain `JavaScript` code that will cause a redirection (I didn't test). But that's irrelevant here as `libcurl` will not run that `JavaScript` code for you.

Comment: You can't with `libcurl`. You need a `JavaScript` engine to run that code (e.g. V8, SpiderMonkey). I don't have much experience in that area. So, I can't help you any further. Sorry.